# Customized DB Connection won't rollback on error (Spring Batch : Chunk)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

In my first Spring Batch chunk job (I'm a beginner), 
I wrote db utility class for using in the chunk step,
since I need to overwrite default connection attributes set by application.properties.

However, it causes rollback problem (never rollback) on errors.
Any advices to improve these logics?

DBUtility class

```
// Construct
public DBUtility() {
  ... some business logic to get connection attributes dynamically.
}

@Bean
@BatchDataSource
@Primary
public DriverManagerDataSource getConnection() {
  DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverNameGottenAbove);
    dataSource.setUrl(urlGottenAbove);
    dataSource.setUsername(userNameGottenAbove);
    dataSource.setPassword(passwordGottenAbove);

  return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(){
  DataSourceTransactionManager dtm = new DataSourceTransationManager(getConnection());
  dtm.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
  return dtm;
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){
  return new JdbcTemplate(getConnection());
}
```

BatchConfiguration class(chunk)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Transactional
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
  ...
  private DBUtility dbUtil;
  private DriverManagerDataSource ds;
  private PlatformTransactionManager ptm;

  // Construct
  public BatchConfiguration(){
    dbUtil = new DBUtility();
    ds = dbUtil.getConnection();
    ptm = dbUtil.transactionManager();
  }

  // Override
  @Override
  public JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
      factory.setDataSource(ds);
      factory.setTransactionManager(ptm);
    JobRepository repo = factory.getObject();
    return repo;
  }

  @Bean
  public Job BatchJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("BatchJob")
      .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
      .listener(jobListener())
      .flow(step1())
      .end().build();
  }

  @Bean
  public step step1() {
    DefaultTransactionAttribute att = new DefaultTransactionAttribute();
      att.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.REQUIRED.value());

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
      .transactionManager(ptm)
      .listener(stepListener())
      .<Entity, Entity>chunk(COMMIT_INTERVAL)
      .reader(reader())
      .processor(processore())
      .writer(writer())
      .readerIsTransactionalQueue()
      .transactionAttribute(att)
      .build();
  }

  ...

}
```

Thank you for checking this post.

Comment: It seems that you are setting two different transaction managers on the job repository (ptm) and on the step (transactionManager). Is this intended?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thank you for your comment. It was my miss-copy, and actually I set "ptm" both at  "createJobRepository()" and "step1()". => fixed above

Comment: Adding `@Transactional` on `BatchConfiguration` is not needed (this means methods on this class should run in a transaction which does not make sense for configuration code). `Propagation.REQUIRED` is already the default, why are you creating a `DefaultTransactionAttribute` in that case? The `stepBuilderFactory` will set the transaction manager on the step, you don't need to do it yourself. Now for your issue, which error you are expecting to rollback the transaction? Is it an exception during reading/processing/writing etc? When does it happen?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I tried & add various options in vain... I should clean these unused codes. As for my issue... I call `DBUtility` & `jdbcTemplate()` in ItemReader, for updating tables in certain conditions. Also I call them in CustomItemWriter for chunk commit. Exceptions occur in reader, processor, and writer, each throwing `RuntimeException`. When an exception occurs, framework always logged `Rollback for RuntimeException`, `Initiating transaction rollback on application exception`, but data (updated in reader & writer) remains in tables.

Comment: As for ItemReader, I changed to use `TransactionTemplate` with PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW definition, for manual transaction (and rollback). Then I added `TransactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()` in catch block. Even in this way, framework logged 'rolling back' but never done. It might not be framework issue..